# How to connect laravel env to SQL Google Cloud?

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-cloud-sql

I try to connect my Laravel project from my .env to Google Cloud SQL.
I already running my .env on local and it works.
This is my local .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=btsalogistics
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD="password here"
```

and it running well to the database locally,
and when I try to deploy it on my Cpanel, I change it into

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=34.101.175.157
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=btsalogistics
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=passwordhere
```

it won't work well, and it returns an error.

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'207.180.206.103' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from blogs order by created_at desc)`

and it same as all of my pages that connected to the database.

The solutions that I have been made is, add my VPS's public IP into my connections setup on SQL cloud google

Anyone can help me to solve this?
Thank you before

Comment: if you password or any variable contain special character you must quote it like DB_PASSWORD='52532#$%#'

Comment: Wow.. I miss that.. My fault.. 
Thank you sir... :)

Comment: iis it wortking

Comment: Yes sir. It is work. Thank you sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have environment variable that contain special characters, then we need to quote it like below. Here's an example:

```
 DB_PASSWORD = '52532#$%#'
```